# Connect HTML files to WAMP database on another machine

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

So I'm developing a Raspberry Pi project that needs access to a database, however the database is stored locally on my laptop through WAMP. I have the Pi as a hotspot so that i can exchange files over and back through SSH however I'm struggling to get it to connect to the WAMP database to display the information that I want it to, what is the best way to do this? I've added my PHP and HTML file below.

HTML & PHP:

```
<?php
    //Step 1
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'hospital') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            PHP connect to MySQL
        </h1>
        <table>
        <?php
            //Step 2
            $query = "SELECT * FROM patients";
            mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');

            $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

            echo "<table border = '1'>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>patient_name</th>
                    <th>check_in_date</th>
                    <th>room_number</th>
                    <th>bed_number</th>
                    <th>notes</th>
                </tr>";

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['patient_name'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['check_in_date'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['room_number'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['bed_number'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            echo "</table>";

            //while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            //  echo $row['id'] . ' ' .</tr> $row['patient_name']. ' ' . $row['check_in_date'] . ' ' . $row['room_number'] . ' ' . $row['bed_number'] . ' ' . $row['notes'] . '<br />';
            //}
        ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when you use  mysqli_connect function .. the first parameter needs to be the address( or ip address) of the MySql server that is hosting the database ... in your code you are using localhost  and probably this is way is not working ...

Comment: I changed the first parameter to my laptops IP address but it still doesn't seem to work, any other suggestions?

Comment: you probably have a firewall on your laptop ... check you can actually reach your mysql server ... you may need to allow access to mysql specific port(the default port is 3306) ... would be nice if you can provide some info about the error you get back

Comment: How can I check if it can reach the MySQL server? Sorry I'm not great at this... The only error I receive is one saying 'Forbidden. You do not have permission to access / on this server'

Comment: so it is a permission problem ... when you try to connect I see you use the user root but no password ... try setting a password for root and use this password as a parameter on your connect function  like in this example: mysqli_connect("server ip address", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");